# How can i get the if else statement working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-tag-manager, google-tag-manager-server-side

I want to implement a if else javascript code in my gtm that will send a popup to tell my visitors on my website that if adblock is enabled they have to disable to proceed. The code below doesn't seem to be working because its always the same statement that is displayed.

```
var adBlockDetected = false;

if (adblockerDetected()) {  
  adBlockDetected = true;  

  alert("Varning! Du har en adblocker aktiverad. Vänligen inaktivera den för att se alla annonser på vår webbplats.");
}

function adblockerDetected() {}
if (!adBlockDetected) {  
  alert("Adblocker är inaktiverat. Du kommer att se alla annonser på vår webbplats.");
}
```

Comment: add `return` in ifs

Comment: what do u want to achieve doing `function adblockerDetected() {}`?

Comment: It looks like you have syntax problems. Your function has nothing in its block. Good formatting and a good editor make that sort of thing obvious.

Comment: So adblockerDetected returns nothing so how would it ever go into that if statement? Did you leave out code on purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Code implementation must be inside of `adblockerDetected()` function:

```
function adblockerDetected() {
 if (!adBlockDetected) {  
  alert("Adblocker är inaktiverat. Du kommer att se alla annonser 
   på vår webbplats.");
}
}
```